# How to open UINavigationController Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to open a UINavigationController programmatically.
Here is my code:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard"
  bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerID"];
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
   initWithRootViewController:vc];
nc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationNone;
[self presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I keep getting the following Error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

Comment: I've pushed navigation controllers exactly like this plenty of times, except that I've created the rootViewController (vc in your code) with initWithNib: bundle:   I suggest temporarily changing the creation of the viewController (maybe use a plain UIViewController rather than your own class) to that to see if it works.  I am guessing maybe your problem is how this viewController is wired into the storyboard.

Comment: I'm guessing your `vc` is actually a `UINavigationController` and not a `UIViewController`.  You also shouldn't be setting `modalTransitionStyle` to `UIModalPresentationNone`, that's not even the right type of enum.

Answer (score 3):

you are completely right, but instead presenting, just push your navigation controller.

For Ex.

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard"
  bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerID"];
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
initWithRootViewController:vc];
[self pushViewController:nc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

UIViewController *viewControllrer = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bound :nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerID" ];
UINavigationController *rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
self.navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:YES];

Comment: Please edit your question and add the source code in a code block. (You select the code, and click on {} button )

Answer (score -1):

The message is pretty specific. It's telling you that you can't present a navigation controller modally.

Comment: You're right.  The message *is* specific.  I don't think we need an answer to restate what Xcode has already told him.  This answer doesn't resolve the askers problem.

Comment: @nhgrif, the user stated that they were getting an error, and doesn't even ask a question. The *implied* question is "Why am I getting this error." The answer to that question is "because what you are trying to do is not allowed", which is exactly what my answer says.

Answer (score -1):

Create the navigation controller inside the view controller.  Add as subview the referenced nav controller's view in another presented view controller.

Comment: While this might work, it's *really* not the right thing to do at all.

Comment: How is having a modal that has its own navigation controller *not* the right thing to do?

Comment: You've suggested he embed a navigation controller inside a view controller. That's impossible.